# Autounattended.xml & GPT partitions

Tags: windows-7, automated-install, unattended, gpt

We are trying to setup an unattended install of windows 7 to a gpt partition on a Lenovo U410, which has UEFI bios.

[This webpage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744271%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) outlines how to format the disk for GPT. If add the default configuration, from the page, to the autounattended.xml file I get the error:

```
Windows cannot be install to this disk. The selected disk is of GPT partition style.
```

If we use the, webpage's, recommended configuration from the above page we get an 0x00042465 (VDS_S_EXTEND_FILE_SYSTEM_FAILED) error, outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd208031%28v=prot.10%29.aspx)

This is our xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This answer file generated by RT Seven Lite-->
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
  <settings pass="windowsPE">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="NonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <SetupUILanguage>
        <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
      </SetupUILanguage>
      <InputLocale>0409:00000409</InputLocale>
      <UserLocale>en-GB</UserLocale>
      <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
      <SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="NonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <!-- Lifted from Document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463140.aspx -->
        <DiskConfiguration>
          <Disk wcm:action="add">
            <DiskID>1</DiskID> 
            <WillWipeDisk>true</WillWipeDisk> 
            <CreatePartitions>

              <!-- System partition (ESP) -->
              <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                <Order>1</Order> 
                <Type>EFI</Type> 
                <Size>260</Size> 
                <!-- Note: for Advanced Format Generation One drives, change to size=260 -->
              </CreatePartition>

              <!-- Microsoft reserved partition (MSR) -->
              <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                <Order>2</Order> 
                <Type>MSR</Type> 
                <Size>128</Size> 
              </CreatePartition>

              <!-- Windows partition -->
              <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                <Order>3</Order> 
                <Type>Primary</Type> 
                <Extend>true</Extend> 
              </CreatePartition>
            </CreatePartitions>

            <ModifyPartitions>

              <!-- System partition (ESP) -->
              <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                <Order>1</Order> 
                <PartitionID>1</PartitionID> 
                <Label>System</Label> 
                <Format>FAT32</Format> 
              </ModifyPartition>

              <!-- The MSR partition does not need to be modified -->

              <!-- Windows partition -->
              <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                <Order>2</Order> 
                <PartitionID>3</PartitionID> 
                <Label>Windows</Label> 
                <Letter>C</Letter> 
                <Format>NTFS</Format> 
              </ModifyPartition>
            </ModifyPartitions>
          </Disk>
          <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI> 
        </DiskConfiguration>
      <ImageInstall>
        <OSImage>
          <InstallFrom>
            <MetaData wcm:action="add">
              <Key>/IMAGE/NAME</Key>
              <value>Windows 7 ENTERPRISE</value>
            </MetaData>
          </InstallFrom>
           <InstallTo>
            <DiskID>1</DiskID>
            <PartitionID>3</PartitionID>
          </InstallTo>
          <InstallToAvailablePartition>false</InstallToAvailablePartition>
          <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
        </OSImage>
      </ImageInstall>
      <UserData>
        <ProductKey>
          <Key>Some-Funky-Key</Key>
          <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
        </ProductKey>
        <Organization>MyCompany</Organization>
        <FullName>Cowboy</FullName>
        <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
      </UserData>
    </component>
  </settings>
  <settings pass="oobeSystem">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="NonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <UserAccounts>
            <LocalAccounts>
                <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                    <Name>Cowboy</Name>
                    <Group>Administrators</Group>
                    <Password>
                        <PlainText>true</PlainText>
                        <Value>Indian</Value>
                    </Password>
                </LocalAccount>
            </LocalAccounts>
        </UserAccounts>
        <OOBE>
            <NetworkLocation>Work</NetworkLocation>
            <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
            <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
        </OOBE>
        <DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>false</DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>
        <TimeZone>GMT Standard Time</TimeZone>
        <AutoLogon>
            <Password>
                <Value>Indian</Value>
                <PlainText>true</PlainText>
            </Password>
            <Domain>.</Domain>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <LogonCount>1</LogonCount>
            <Username>bromine</Username>
        </AutoLogon>
    </component>
  </settings>
  <settings pass="specialize">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="NonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <ComputerName>RENAME_ME</ComputerName>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Licensing-SLC-UX" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="NonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <SkipAutoActivation>true</SkipAutoActivation>
    </component>
  </settings>
</unattend>
```

As I said it's pretty much lifted from the TechNet webpage listed above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Should this be on SuperUser?

Comment: Are you using a 64 bit version of Windows 7? 32 bit versions would not be able to boot from a GPT drive. This information (and more) can be found in the [Windows and GPT FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463525.aspx).

Comment: Sorry, missed this comment. I'm using 64bit windows. Will checkout the link. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 needs an 100mb partition for the Bitlock feature, this is not optional.
I do not know how this exactly translates to your setup but probably:

- partition 1 UEFI
- partition 2 NTFS 100mb
- partition 3 NTFS

Good luck